# Why are messages in DLT using DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer base64 encoded

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have configured a errorHandler which sends records to a DLT using

```
@Bean
    public DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer recoverer(KafkaTemplate<String, List<T>> template) {
        return new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(template);
    }

    @Bean
    public ErrorHandler errorHandler(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer recoverer) {
        return new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler(recoverer, new FixedBackOff(0L, 2L));
    }
```

I am using this DLT to capture serialization errors handled by `ErrorHandlingDeserializer2`

Problem I am facing is the messages in DLT are in base64 encoded format instead of plain string.

Producer
[image]
DLT consumer
[image]

`test message` goes in DLT as `dGVzdCBtZXNzYWdl`

Another problem which is hapenning is request size increases because of base64 encoding.
I want the message to go as is in the DLT.
Could you please provide pointers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Show your producer factory configuration.

Perhaps you are using a common producer factory?

Best guess is you are using a `JsonSerializer` there instead of a `ByteArraySerializer`.

With version 2.5, you can override producer factory configuration in each `KafkaTemplate`.